# Interacting the HTML element below without changing z-indices

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I have to two html elements, element A and element B. Element A is on top of element B wrt their z-indices. Element A is a transparent canvas through which I can see element B. Since element A is above element B, I cannot interact with element B.

Is it possible to interact with the underneath element B without changing the z-indices?

Comment: Where is your source?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in CSS, use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on element a